# Does yum use the rpm executable to handle rpm packages or does it implement its own rpm parsing and handling

Tags: rpm, yum

How does yum work internally?
Does yum shell out to use the rpm executable when actually manipulating rpm files, or does it implement its own rpm handling code? 
(Or does it use a static or shared rpm library for dealing with rpm files)

Comment: You could always look at the source code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems yum is a python implementation building on rpm-python. You can deduce such things by looking at the rpm requirements:

```
rpm -q yum --requires
```

gives:

```
...
rpm-python
...
```

which led me. Also looking a the `/usr/bin/yum` file:

```
file /usr/bin/yum
```

gives

```
/usr/bin/yum: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

Comment: This info is helpful. That same command you mentioned also listed rpm right above rpm-python.  I tried renaming the rpm executable and installing a package to see if yum actually relied on the rpm executable itself and it does not.

Answer (score 0):

After obtaining the source to yum and rpm I found out the following:

yum is implemented in python and uses rpm-python package for rpm access.
Both rpm and yum ultimately utilize the librpm.so shared library for RPM package management at the low level.